# Django writing Middleware to extend self.request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I am very new to writing custom middleware in Django.

We know in Django, there is built-in `self.request`. in `self.request`, there are too many instances like `self.request.user`, `self.request.data`, `self.request.authenticator` etc

I am trying to add `self.request.mycustom`; in `self.request.mycustom`, I want to get my models `MyCustom` instance.

This is My Models:

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class MyCustom(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='auth_user',
    )
```

I am trying to write the middleware but not getting how to write this.

this is my attempt to write:

```
class MessMiddleWare(obect):
    def precess_view(request):
        mycustom = MyCustom.objects.filter(id=request.user.pk)
        request.mycustom = mycustom
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

I just I want to get `self.request.mycustom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

...

class MessMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        mycustom = MyCustom.objects.filter(id=request.user.pk)
        # Instead of using filter, consider doing (if it fits your usecase):
        # mycustom = get_object_or_404(MyCustom, pk=request.user.pk)
        request.mycustom = mycustom
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Do not forget to add your middleware in `MIDDLEWARE` of `settings.py`.

---

Note that it should be `object` and not `obect`.

---

Read more about writing custom middlewares in [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware).